# issue with mockito test for try catch block with slif4j Log

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, testing, mockito

I am writting test for a try catch block, but I am quite confused about how to test the catch block...especially it uses **slf4j** to log the error.

addText here is the another method from the same class.

```
public class TextQueue {
  public void addTextToQueue(final Text text) {
            try {
                if (text != null) {
                    addText(text);
                }
            } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error adding text to the queue : {}", e);
            }
        }
}
```

here is my test case

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TextQueueTest {
private org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TextQueueTest.class);

private static final String MY_TEXT = "src/text.json";
private Text text;
private final ObjectMapper mapper = new JacksonConfig().dateAsStringObjectMapper();

@Mock
private TextQueue textQueue;

@Before
public void setUp() throws IOException {
    text = mapper.readValue(new File(TextQueueTest.MY_TEXT), Text.class);

}

@Test
public void addTextToQueue() {
    try{
        textQueue = spy(textQueue);
        textQueue.addTextToQueue(text);
    }catch(final Exception e){
        LOOGER.error("add text to queue threw an error" + e);
    }
}
```

can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Please note: your updates add to the confusion. Now your test class wouldn't compile any more, and hint: declaring a LOGGER instance in the test class has NO effects whatsoever on your production code. From that point of view, you probably should revisit [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly, if possible. Or let me know what/if is missing from my answer.

Comment: so I shouldn't include LOGGER in the test , to test the catch block in the original method, the best way is to trigger the exception and then verify the exception, right? @GhostCat

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you are "good" with just checking: addTextToQueue() does catch any exception, then the test not throwing an exception would be good enough. But if you want to ensure that some message is written to the logger, then you need to gain control to it. Again: having a LOGGER instance sitting in your test case doesn't do anything in your production code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try to find the method to check the log if the exception throws

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback! As said: the key thing is to gain control over the logger object. You might want to read about dependency injection. The real question is: how does that LOGGER instance get into your production code? When you understand that, you can look at your options. It could be that you can push in a mocked logger, if that isnt possible, yes looking at the "output" of the real logger could do. (but I would advise to avoid that, you want to isolate your unit tests from any "real" thing such as files in your file system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should really read a good tutorial about Mockito, like the one from [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html). You see, you are simply throwing together a lot of things that are **non-sensical**.

Like:

```
@Mock
private TextQueue textQueue;
```

to then have

```
textQueue = spy(textQueue);
```

within your test case. You should be really clear about this. A spy is build on a **real** instance of your class under test. Creating a spy that spies on a mock, as said: that makes no sense.

Then:

```
}catch(final Exception e){
    Logger.error("add text to queue threw an error" + e);
```

Again, non-sensical. The whole idea of your unit tests is that they **fail** when something is wrong. When your production code throws unexpected exceptions, you don't log them, you just let them fail your test case in the end.

To answer the actual question: it *looks* like your production code is using a specific "constant" logger instance. Given that design, the only way to check your production code would be to:

- make that LOGGER a mocked object
- somehow inject it into an instance `underTest` of your production code class
- trigger that method to test on `underTest` (and somehow force the method to throw an exception)
- verify that the mocked LOGGER saw the expected call to `error()`

We can't give better advise, because your code input isn't sufficient, we don't really know what your production class is doing (for example: we don't know what LOGGER is, and where it is coming from. if it happens to be a static variable, then most likely, you can't get "control" over it with Mockito).

In any case, you probably actually need the **spy** concept. In order to test `addTextToQueue()` you need a way to invoke the "real" `addTextToQueue()` implementation, but the call to `addTser()` within needs to go to a mock (so that you can control what that call does).

But as said: start by *really* researching how Mockito works, instead of throwing together things that make no sense in some "trial and error" approach. Correct unit testing with mocking is complicated, you can't learn that by "trial and error".